# Having issues with C# and mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, datareader

I am trying to make a little desktop application to make whitelisting players on my game server more simple. I'm running into some issues. Here's a bit of the code...

```
       private void identityCombo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if(connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            connection.Open();
        }

        jobsCombo.Enabled = true;
        gradesCombo.Enabled = true;
        groupCombo.Enabled = true;

        String query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE identifier=@id";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", identityCombo.SelectedItem);

         MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        groupCombo.Enabled = true;

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            steamNameBox.Text = reader["name"].ToString();
            jobsCombo.SelectedIndex = jobsCombo.FindString(reader["job"].ToString());
            cashBox.Text = "$" + String.Format("{0:n0}", reader["money"].ToString());
            bankBox.Text = "$" + String.Format("{0:n0}", reader["bank"].ToString());
        }

        steamNameBox.Visible = true;
        steamNameLbl.Visible = true;
        cashLbl.Visible = true;
        bankLbl.Visible = true;
        bankBox.Visible = true;
        cashBox.Visible = true;
        bankLbl.Visible = true;
        groupLbl.Visible = true;
        groupCombo.Visible = true;
        phoneNumBox.Visible = true;
        phoneNumLbl.Visible = true;
        esxLbl.Visible = true;
        jobLbl.Visible = true;
        gradesLbl.Visible = true;
        jobsCombo.Visible = true;
        gradesCombo.Visible = true;
        updateInfoBtn.Visible = true;
    }
```

What I'm trying to do is have my login system (works great, no issue there), but then it brings up another menu. On the server, you can have multiple identities. I have a way of selecting them and all just fine.

Here's my problem:

```
       while (reader.Read())
        {
            steamNameBox.Text = reader["name"].ToString();
            jobsCombo.SelectedIndex = jobsCombo.FindString(reader["job"].ToString());
            cashBox.Text = "$" + String.Format("{0:n0}", reader["money"].ToString());
            bankBox.Text = "$" + String.Format("{0:n0}", reader["bank"].ToString());
        }
```

I am changing the "jobsCombo.SelectedIndex", which triggers an event that I have setup which will load the "job grades" (ranks) based off of the selected job.

```
    private void jobsCombo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        loadJobGrades(jobsCombo.SelectedItem.ToString());
    }
```

Here's a picture of the interface to give more detail.

[image]

All of the information is procedurally pulled from the database, the job is automatically selected from the ComboBox on the left based on what they have in the DB. Alright, problem -- when changing the "job" selection, it's supposed to populate the job ranks for it on the right, but it's not.

```
        private void loadJobGrades(String job)
    {

        String query = "SELECT * FROM job_grades WHERE job_name=@job";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@job", job);

        MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        MessageBox.Show("1");
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            gradesCombo.Items.Add(reader["label"]);
            MessageBox.Show("2");
        }
    }
        private void jobsCombo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        loadJobGrades(jobsCombo.SelectedItem.ToString());
    }
```

The second section of code is supposed to load the grades/ranks based off the currently selected "job" box.

Problem with the first code is that **I need to create/execute a new reader, which is the problem**. I get "There is already an open DataReader associated with this connection" because it's running from an event, which is also triggered by populating the combobox.

I've been trying to figure this out for 10 hours, please help.

Comment: You forgot to *close* the reader. In all the All ADO.NET tutorials you'll see that the connection, command and reader are created inside `using` blocks. Global connections *aren't* used, a new one is created and opened each time. Connection pooling ensures this is a cheap operation

Comment: So should I just put everything inside using blocks and it'll magically fix it? If I open a reader for the part where I'm getting the info from the reader to populate the job combo and setting the index, it fires the index change event which would be opening another reader.

Comment: Basically what I'm saying is my datareader that is getting the info and selecting their job on the left combobox also triggers the event which is opening a new data reader, and because I open a new reader and close it, the rest of the things inside the first datareader can't complete because that reader is now closed. If that makes sense..? @Panagiotis Kanavos

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos had to switch to desktop mode on my phone to mention